# Selenium: Presence of a particular WebElement on all pages in the website

Tags: selenium, webdriver

We have a search widget at the top of the page in all the pages. I want to check, if that widget is visible on all the pages of the website. Is there any smarter way, rather than going to all the pages and checking it?

Comment: You should talk to dev and ask if that widget is some shared component on each page and how you might make your tests more efficient. Other than going to each page, I don't know how you are going to actually verify it on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Answering straight, when you want to check if an widget is visible or not we should have used a method `isVisible()`. But `isVisible()` was available in `Selenium RC` which is deprecated in current `WebDriver` implementations. Instead referring to the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) we can use either of these methods `isDisplayed()`, `isEnabled()` or `isSelected()`.

So when you speak about `search widget at the top of the page in all the pages` I feel **`isDisplayed()`** method fits into your requirement. For example let us take an example of the `Search` field on `stackoverflow.com` Homepage which is available on all the pages. Now we want to `check, if that widget is visible on all the pages of the website` or not. A sample code block can be as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class A_Firefox 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
        System.out.println("Application opened");
        System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
        WebElement my_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']"));
        if(my_element.isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("Element is displayed");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Element is not displayed");
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The output on my console is:

```
Application opened
Page Title is : Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
Element is displayed
```

### Enhancement:

As an enhancement you can create a function as `presenceOfSearchBox(WebElement ele)` and pass the `WebElement` as an argument from every page you visit to validate if the widget is displayed or not as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class A_Firefox 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
        System.out.println("Application opened");
        System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
        WebElement my_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']"));
        presenceOfSearchBox(my_element);
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void presenceOfSearchBox(WebElement ele)
    {
        if(ele.isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("Element is displayed");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Element is not displayed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, I have to go through all the pages and check. I am looking for some smarter way to check. For example, to check if all pages are working in our website, rather than opening each page, we do check the http getResponseMessage. I am looking for some smarter solution like this.

Comment: `Selenium` needs the focus on a particular page to detect if any element is `Displayed` on the `DOM tree` of the page or not.